# Django not decoding urls properly

Tags: html, django, hyperlink, django-templates, python-3.7

The django server is not decoding the get url and sending a 404 error.

The django message was as follow:

```
 "GET /static/website/css/colors5533.css%3Fcolor%3D0A8F89 HTTP/1.1" 404 1751
```

The website source code for the url in the browser was shown as follows:

```
href="/static/website/css/colors5533.css%3Fcolor%3D0A8F89"
```

The code in the template of the django project was as follows:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'website/css/colors5533.css?color=0A8F89' %} type="text/css" />
```

and also coded the link as follows but that doesn't seem to work either

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/colors5533.css' %}?color=0A8F89" type="text/css" />
```

Any solutions to the problem?

Comment: _"that doesn't seem to work"_: What happened with the second method?

Comment: @Selcuk the second method was not working either.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but explain "not working".